# Where can I download the software RPM for Redhat？

Tags: linux, rhel, rpm

I try to download some software RPMs(such as gcc, gdb, etc.) for Redhat enterprise version. But after googling, I only find this website:https://access.redhat.com/downloads. This site doesn't seem to provide these software RPMs.

Could anyone give some clues about where is the right site? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: That's the right link, there's an RPM package search link in the sidebar on the right.

Comment: @Mat: But I find the RPMs are very old. E.g., the gcc version is 3.2.3.

Comment: Well, yeah, there's RPMs for old versions. But the new ones are there too. Search some more.

Comment: @Mat: I try to search, but still can't find the newest RPMs. If possible, could you give me a link? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when you buy a RedHat license, you get access for one year to their repository.  In otherwords, access to RedHat specific packages is by paid license ONLY.  Your company should have access to these packages, so you'll have to ask your company systems administrator for registering your system properly to obtain such packages.

However, as you know Centos is built from the non-proprietary sources of RedHat and many packages are available.  Thus their repository COULD be viable and useable in a RHEL system.

Of note, RedHat backports patches into their RPM repositories without necessarily changing the major/minor version.  Thus what might appear to be an older RedHat RPM version might indeed be up-to-date using patches.